# dc.js - how to dynamically modify cell size in heatmap?

Tags: visualization, heatmap, dc.js, crossfilter

Is there a way in dc.js to change the size of a cell in a heatmap based on the underlying data? I.e. like with colors:

```
heatmap.colorAccessor(d => d.x) // Access attribute x as basis for cell colour.
```

I'm trying to achieve [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381273/heatmap-with-circles-indicating-size-of-population), but couldn't figure out a way to dynamically modify the cell size so far without rewriting the heatmap code itself.

Comment: Unfortunately I think you are correct. What’s more, the cells are rounded rectangles not circles.

Comment: Circle or rectangle is not really relevant to me. Thanks for the info though, I just modified the heatmap code directly. If you post this as an answer, I'll accept it.