# How to add a hline or vline to a plotly express legend in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, plotly-python

I'm trying to add my hline to the legend and label it as 'mean'. Is this possible and if so how.

Example

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': np.repeat(np.arange(1, 11, 1), 2),
                   'value': np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4),
                   'var': list(['A', 'B']) * 10})

fig = px.bar(df,
             x='day',
             y='value',
             color='var')

fig.add_hline(y=df['value'].mean(), line_dash="dot")

fig.show()
```

Expected outcome
[image]

Comment: The legend can be called itself and accepts I believe a dictionary of items. I would start wit the modified answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65654470/13627227 here... I believe it is the last few lines in a variable called c, that is then passed into plt.legend()

Comment: Does it matter for you if it's under "A" and "B" - or can it be right above the dotted line?

Comment: @thejahcoop, that looks like matplotlib. not plotly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `annotation_text` parameter in `fig.add_hline`:

```py
fig.add_hline(y=df['value'].mean(), line_dash="dot", annotation_text="mean")
```

That would add a text right above the dotted line:

[image]

However, the text will not be right under the "Var" section.
In order to do this, you will need to change it from `add_hline` to `add_trace` as it is not subject to the legend:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame({'day': np.repeat(np.arange(1, 11, 1), 2),
                   'value': np.repeat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4),
                   'var': list(['A', 'B']) * 10})

fig = px.bar(df,
             x='day',
             y='value',
             color='var')

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=df['day'],
    y=[df['value'].mean()] * len(df['day']),
    mode='lines',
    name='mean',
    line=dict(dash='dot', width=2, color='black'),
))

fig.show()
```

Which results in this figure:

[image]